# gsap Flip.fit svg element not moving to expected coordinates because of { duration: x }

Tags: animation, svg, gsap

I am confused with gsap's  Flip.fit moving to coordinates.

I have a game board with 182 tiles and 182 playing tiles.

**The goal**

When the user clicks the bag, a random playing tile is selected and is "supposed" to move over the tile on the board.

If you change

```
Flip.fit(PTILE[tileArray], TILE[tileArray], {duration: 1 , scale: true});
```

when changing { duration: **0**, ... }  the move works as expected, however no animation. When duration is above zero, the final location is very random.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/simonatmuldev/pen/podNPyJ?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out that Inkscape stores the SVG with inline transforms that threw the animation off. I tried saving in plain or optimised, but still had no luck.

So there are two solutions.

1. Use [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) an online SVG cleaner.
2. Use [Affinity Designer](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/designer/) application which can export and flatten transforms.

###### The key to rule out other factors is to use relative coordinates and flatten transforms.

I have included a screenshot of Affinity exporting options.
[Affinity Export screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcxJd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the duration affects the final position, however, I found a way to get the positions right. That is reset the `transform` of your `PTILE` before telling GSAP to do the Flip animation.

```js
// reset transform value
gsap.set(PTILE[tileArray], { transform: "" });

// animate with new transform value
Flip.fit(PTILE[tileArray], TILE[tileArray], {
    duration: 1,
    scale: true
});
```

My reason is that `PTITLE` and `TITLE` are placed in different `<g>` tags which means **their transform systems are inconsistent**. Plus, `Flip.fit()` will act like `gsap.to()` with new `TITLE` position is the `to` object, GSAP will try to calculate the `from` object from your original transforms which are already set in the SVG as `transform:matrix()`. This process, somehow, is messing up. So what I did is give GSAP an exact transform value for the `from` object, which is empty.

Comment: Thanks phucbm, you are right about the transform. I found an online service that flatten transforms and simply fixes the problem without having to change anything else.
https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/